# selecting multiple ranges of records from the results of the first part of query

Tags: sqlite

I've got a query which produces a timestamp range in each row.  For example:

```
    t1         |      t2
1630107688.249 | 1630108063.66
1630114810.843 | 1630115371.65
1630122262.41  | 1630122744.526
1630156417.937 | 1630160941.348
1630197848.644 | 1630198370.975
```

In another table I have a timestamp field "t".  I want to select all records from this table that have a value of t which is one of the ranges found by my query.

If the above was a static number of ranges, I would write a query something like this:

```
SELECT *
From MyTable
WHERE t BETWEEN 1630107688.249 AND 1630108063.66
   OR t BETWEEN 1630114810.843 AND 1630115371.65
   OR t BETWEEN 1630122262.41  AND 1630122744.526
   OR t BETWEEN 1630156417.937 AND 1630160941.348
   OR t BETWEEN 1630197848.644 AND 1630198370.975;
```

But I don't know ahead of time what the ranges will be or how many there will be.  There could be tens or hundreds of ranges.

Is there a way I can construct a query to join or otherwise use the results of my first query to select records in any of the ranges returned?

I tried this:

```
WITH R(t1,t2)
AS
(
   << my query to get t1,t2 rows>>
)
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE t BETWEEN (SELECT t1 FROM R) AND (SELECT t2 FROM R);
```

But for my example table of t1,t2 rows above, it only returned records with timestamps between 1630107688.249 and 1630108063.66, meaning that it's ignoring everything but the first row returned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM MyTable m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM R WHERE m.t BETWEEN R.t1 AND R.t2);
```